# How to enable or disable a Highcharts tooltip when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

This is what I've tried:

```
$("#toollip").click(function(){
    if(chart.container.tooltip.enabled ){
        chart.container.tooltip.enabled = false;
    }else{
        chart.container.tooltip.enabled  = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that `jQuery` is my best guess.

Comment: The code you have posted should work, assuming `chart.container` refers to `new Highcharts.Chart(...)`, `#tooltip` is the intended element, the code is properly wrapped in `$(document).ready( ... )` and jQuery is properly included.

Comment: Note that it's a good practice to stay and reply to comments so that you can supply any information we need in order to answer your question.

Comment: So, please post more code: Where do you assign `chart` or `chart.container`, some HTML... . To rule out the latter two, I ask for the entire page of yours.

Answer (score 6):

I looked through a lot of forums and nowhere I found very easy way to show/hide a Tooltip like tooltip.enable = true/false. The good way I came to is to set tooltip setting through Formatter in the initialization of chart.

var barsShowen - is a global variable that has a necessary state - true/false - show Tooltip or not.

```
tooltip: {
  shared: true,
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function () {
    if (barsShowen) {
      var s = '<span><b>' + this.x + '</b></span><table>';
      $.each(this.points, function () {
        s += '<tr><td align = "left" style = "color:' + this.series.color + ';">' + this.series.name + ': ' + '</td>' +
          '<td><b>' + this.y + '</b></td></tr>';
      });
      return s + '</table>';
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works! This is the correct answer for this question.

Comment: I found this is the easiest way to toggle (show/hide) tooltip in Highcharts.  It also works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can `chart.update()` in compination with tooltip style property.

To Hide Tooltip

```
chart.update({
    tooltip: {
        style: {
            display: "none",
        }
    }
});
```

To show Tooltip

```
  chart.update({
              tooltip: {
                  style: {
                      display: "block",
                  }
              }
   });
```

Chek this out

https://jsfiddle.net/parveennp/1kbo8100/5/

Answer (score 3):

Based on Praveen N's answer you can also enable or disable the tooltip using `chart.update()`

```
chart.update({
    tooltip: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

Comment: More on this from the Highcharts API docs: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.enabled

Answer (score 2):

Try this (just a demo how u can achieve it):

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
        if (status) {
            return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' + this.point.series.name + ': ' + this.y;

        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . is there a method to control all chart's options from the outside, or after loading ??

Comment: It does not work. The tooltip still displayed, but without text.

Answer (score 1):

Stop it from displaying using basic CSS and the HighChart.update method :

```
chart.update({
    tooltip: {
        style: {
            display: "none",
        }
    }
});
```

This way your chart's tooltip will not appear until you apply CSS to make it show up. Also, I think your example code should work but you maybe have a typo :

```
$("#toollip").click(function(){
```

maybe should be

```
$("#tooltip").click(function(){
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

If you write about "Series" point tooltip, you will need this option:

```
enableMouseTracking: false,
```

In code:

```
$(function () { 
    var Chart = Highcharts.chart('Chart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
        },
        title: {
            text: Chart,
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1', '2', '3'],
        },
        yAxis: {

        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Line',
            data: [10, 20, 30,],
            enableMouseTracking: false,
        },],
    });
});
```

This is [official JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-enablemousetracking-false/).

Also you can remove all marker points from line by using the option:

```
marker: {
    enabled: false,
},
```

Other options for markers you can find [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.marker).